# SwiftUI Loaded async images are not showing

Tags: swift, image, asynchronous, swiftui, xml-parsing

I would like to load images async from the xml file to my SwiftUI View, but it doesn't work. The loaded images are not showing. But if I use **Data(contentsOf: imageURL)** method is everything fine!

Have you any idea?

Here is the xml parser snippet:

```
// 2
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    
    if elementName == "item" {
        let imageURL = URL(string: podcastImage)!
        //let imageData = try! Data(contentsOf: imageURL) // load sync and works
        //let image = UIImage(data: imageData) // load sync and works
        let remoteImageLoader = ImageLoader(imageURL: imageURL)  // Async not showing images
        let image = UIImage(data: remoteImageLoader.data) // Async not showing images
        podcasts.append(
            Station(
                name: podcastTitle,
                detail: "Podcast",
                url: URL(string: podcastURL)!,
                image: image,
                imageUrl: podcastImage
        ))
    }
    
}
```

Here is the Imageloader

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

class ImageLoader: ObservableObject {

@Published var data: Data = Data()

init(imageURL: URL) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: imageURL) { data, response, error in
        guard let recievedData = data, error == nil  else {
            print("Error: No Data")
            return
        }
        print("Got Data") // Doesn't output to console
        print(recievedData) // Doesn't output to console
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.data = recievedData
        }
    }
    .resume()
  }
}
```

Podcasts are struct like that and I use it inside other File/View

```
struct Station: Identifiable, Hashable {
var id = UUID()
let name: String
let detail: String
let url: URL
var image: UIImage?
let imageUrl: String


init(name: String, detail: String, url: URL, image: UIImage? = nil, imageUrl: String) {
    self.name = name
    self.detail = detail
    self.url = url
    self.image = image
    self.imageUrl = imageUrl
}

}
```

Comment: The data parameter in your ImageLoader is marked as @Published, but you aren't subscribing to it, so you don't get notified when the the data is asynchronously available.

Comment: @Abizen thank you for your answer! I am new to swift programming. Could you explain this in more detail? I save the images to podcasts: type [Station] and want show it inside other View as a List.

Comment: You're using a `Published` variable - which means you are using the `Combine` framework. It's a lot to cover in a short answer. I recommend you look up the documentation or some tutorials about that framework

Comment: @Leff You are instantly doing `UIImage(data: remoteImageLoader.data)`, before `data` would have been set to anything. I think it's currently just `Data()` still. What is that `parser` function in, a class? View struct?